# Sort integer in Ascending Order - Java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I need help understanding how to sort numbers.
Below is what I have I came up with so far and it didn't work. Can you please point out the mistake and tell me what to do?

I saw some of you guys using `java.util.Arrays` . Can you describe to me its functions?

```
import static java.lang.System.*;
import java.util.*;

    public class Lab07v2_Task10{
    public static void main (String[] args){
            Scanner orcho = new Scanner (in);
            int quantity = 5;
            int[] myArray = new int [quantity];
            out.println("Please enter 5 numbers");

            for(int count = 0; count<myArray.length; count++){
                myArray[count] = orcho.nextInt();
            }

            int maxSoFar = myArray[0];

            for(int count = myArray.length-1; count>=0; count--){
                if(myArray[count] > maxSoFar){
                maxSoFar = myArray[count];
            }
            out.println(maxSoFar);
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could just use `Arrays.sort`...

Comment: @Mena that's kind of beside the point, you should be able to sort numbers "by hand" even if you use `Arrays.sort`

Comment: @Maljam which is why it's a comment, not an answer. Just trying to make OP's life easier here. The `Arrays` and `Collections` methods are known to be highly optimized. Implementing your own algorithm might be pointless, even when learning. You could just copy from the source instead.

Comment: [Here's a good place to start.](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~adamchik/15-121/lectures/Sorting%20Algorithms/sorting.html)

Comment: for learning purposes, you should first read about [sorting algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm), but by the size of your array, you could figure out a simple algorithm by your own...

Comment: As this is clearly programming exercise I don't think using Arrays.sort() really teaches you much. You can try implementing a simple bubble sort which is explained here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort#Step-by-step_example

Comment: *Can you describe to me its functions?*: that's exactly what the javadoc is for. Learn to read it. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html

Answer (score 2):

No solution.
The idea is to take several steps, do a for-loop. And assume that you are in the middle. The first part already is sorted, the rest is to-be-done.

Then tackle the current element with respect to what already is sorted.

```
int maxSoFar = myArray[0];
for (int i = 1; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    // The array 0, ..., i-1 is sorted
    if (myArray[i] >= maxSoFar) {
        // Still sorted
        maxSoFar = myArray[i];
    } else {
        // myArray[i] must be shifted left
        ...
    }
    // Now the array 0, ..., i is sorted
}
```

This is a general trick: assume part is already done, tackle one small step, and let continue.

Answer (score 1):

The `java.util.Arrays.sort(int[])` method sorts the specified **array** of `int` into ascending numerical order.

try this out..

```
// sorting array
  java.util.Arrays.sort(myArray);

   // let us print all the elements available in list
   System.out.println("The sorted int array is:");
   for (int number : myArray) {
   System.out.println("Number = " + number);
   }
   }
```

`Arrays.sort` is a method which is a utility method available in `java.util` package.

Where `Arrays` is a system defined Utility class which contains the mehtod `sort(int[])` takes `int[]` (array) as an argument and after sorting this array, It re-assign Array.

For more deep Info [Here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/arrays_sort_int.htm) or [Official Java Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html)

Answer (score 1):

The way your program runs right now: it will print 5 numbers and the number that it prints is the highest number it finds at that iteration.

The way that you want it to work: sort 5 numbers from lowest to highest. Then print these 5 numbers. This is an implementation of bubble sort in your program:

```
for(int i = 0; i< myArray.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < myArray.length-1; j++){
            if(myArray[j] > myArray[j+1]){ //if the current number is less than the one next to it
                int temp = myArray[j]; //save the current number 
                myArray[j] = myArray[j+1]; //put the one next to it in its spot
                myArray[j+1] = temp; //put the current number in the next spot
            }
        }
    }
```

it is probably the easiest sort to understand. Basically, for as many times as the length of your array, comb over the numbers and bring the next highest number as far up as it can go.

When it's done sorting you can then print the numbers.

Comment: Thanks! using a temp helps!